# Where is "==" method in Scala List API?

Tags: scala

I am reading "Programming in Scala" book, it mentioned `==` is `final` in class `Any`, which mean subclass is not able to override it, so when I see this example `List(1,2) == List(1,2)`, I went to find the [API](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html) doc, I couldn't find the method `==`, how Scala define that method in `List` actually? Why it is not in the API doc?

If it is not overwriten by `List` class, how the comparison can be based on `List` item instead of object reference?

Comment: Seem like I have asked a stupid question. I thought `val a = List(1,2)` and `val b = List(1,2)` has same object reference, because they are immutable like string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`==` is a final method in class `Any`, and it calls `.equals`.

> Q: how Scala define that method in List actually?
>
> A: Every class in a Scala execution environment inherits directly or
>   indirectly from `Any` class.

Reference equality in Scala is `eq`.

Answer (score 1):

**== is final in class Any**, and `Any` is the root in the **scala** class hierarchy. every class in **scala** it will extend from `Any` default. so when call the `==` in **scala**, it will call **Any** `==` method firstly. and for the `Any` `==` defnition:

> if (x eq null) that eq null else x.equals(that)

See: [Any Class](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/Any.html#==(x$1:Any):Boolean)